# Spring Data Custom Method Error : org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property xxx found for type

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to create base repository class to add new custom methods, but getting errors.

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface XRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {
Optional<T> xxx(ID id);
}

public class XRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements XRepository<T, ID> {

    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    public XRepositoryImpl(JpaEntityInformation entityInformation, EntityManager entityManager) {
        super(entityInformation, entityManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<T> xxx(ID id) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(findOne(id));
    }
}

public interface BookRepository extends XRepository<Book, Long> {
}
```

Stack Trace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property xxx found for type Book!
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:77) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:329) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:309) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

I've checked answers to same problem but they didn't help. They are pointing out to naming convention, I can't see any problem with that.

Comment: How have you configured Spring Data JPA to pick up this custom implementation?

Comment: I didn't do any additional configuration. I thought extending the repository (_BookRepository_) from the base would be enough

Comment: no it is not sufficient to just provide a custom implementation for repositories. You also need to point the Spring Data infrastructure to your custom implementation. See [the reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-behaviour-for-all-repositories) for details.

Comment: You are right @Manish. It seems like I needed extra configuration. If you add solution as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Hi @Ozzy, glad to know it worked for you.

Comment: Thanks, It works with configuration @manish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Manish pointed out, there was a configuration I was missing:

> To make the Spring Data infrastructure aware of the customized repository
>   base class using @EnableJpaRepositories

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryBaseClass = XRepositoryImpl.class)
class ApplicationConfiguration { … }
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring data mongo works on naming convention of the classes. If your repository interface is named XXXRepository, then your custom Repository interface should be named as XXXRespositoryCustom(RepositoyName + Custom) and your implementation class should be named as XXXRepositoryImpl. Only then your custom implementations will be read.

Answer (score 0):

You are close, but your class naming is what is causing your problem.  Try this:

```
public interface XRepositoryOperations<T, ID extends Serializable> {
    Optional<T> xxx(ID id);
}

public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, Long>, XRepositoryOperations<Book, Long> {
}

public class XRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> implements XRepositoryOperations<T, ID> {

    @Autowired private BookRepository bookRepository;

    @Override
    public Optional<T> xxx(ID id) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(bookRepository.findOne(id));
    }
}
```

With your current class definitions, Spring is looking through BookRepository to XRepository as the class that will be used to implement the API.  It is trying to implement your `xxx` method using its [method-name-to-query translation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation).  If you want to exempt methods from this method auto-implementation, you need to define them in a separate interface, and then have your repository interface extend it.  This is the class that will be implemented in the `Impl` repository class that you will define.

*Edit*

Another option, if you are using Java 8 and want to keep everything in the base class, would be to supply a default implementation of the `xxx` method:

```
public interface XRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository {

    default Optional<T> xxx(ID id) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(this.findOne(id));
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm trying to have a base repository class. I don't think, letting base class have child classes as field is a good design.

Comment: Your options here are limited.  If you want a custom method in your base repository class, you either have to 1) name it so that the auto-query-generator will accept it, 2) provide a `@Query` annotation with the query definition (remember, `Optional<?>` is a valid return type for a `findOne` operation), or 3) supply a default implementation (see my edit above).

Answer (score -1):

you're using Spring Data JPA. you have to use `@Repository` in your Repository. and also use below code into your ApplicationContext.xml :

```
<context:component-scan annotation-config="true"
    base-package="com.demo.test" />

<context:annotation-config />
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.demo.test.repository" />
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

Comment: spring repositories are picked even without @Repository annotation.